# Saving a frustrating simple Canvas drawn image to a local web folder?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas that allows user to draw on it with brushes.

JS

```
var sketcher = null;
 var brush = null;


$(document).ready(function(e) {
localStorage.setItem("clickCount", 0);
var alpha = localStorage.getItem("alpha");
if(!alpha){
    alpha = 10;
}
alpha = (parseInt(alpha))/10;
console.log(alpha);
//Get Brush Opacity
var power = localStorage.getItem("power");
var expo = localStorage.getItem("expo");
power = parseInt(power);
expo = parseInt(expo);
var opacity = ((expo / 100)+ 1) * (power / 10) / 100;

console.log(opacity);
var standBy = localStorage.getItem("standBy");
var brushSize = localStorage.getItem("spotDiameter");
brush = new Image();
brush.src = 'assets/brush_spot_'+ brushSize + '.png';
// brush.src = 'assets/brush_spot_'+ brushSize +"_"+ alpha + '.png';
if(standBy == "false"){
    brush.onload = function(){
        sketcher = new Sketcher( "sketch", brush );
        var canvas = document.getElementById('sketch');
        var c =  canvas.getContext("2d");
        c.globalAlpha = opacity;
    }
}

$("#sketch").css("cursor", "url(assets/cursor_spot_"+ brushSize +"_"+ alpha +".ico) 12 12, auto");
var clickCount = 0;
$('#sketch').click(function(e){
    if(standBy == "true"){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
     else{
        clickCount++;
        localStorage.setItem("clickCount", clickCount);
        $("#clickCount").text(clickCount);
    }


});
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="sketch" width="1024" />
<canvas id="draw"/>
```

I have two dependant js files that load before the webpage sketcher.js and trignometry.js .

What I need to do is save whatever is drawn on the canvas to either localstorage or as a temp file in a local folder that can be recalled everytime the canvas loads.

Comment: I am using this function                                      var dataURL = sketch.toDataURL();
 console.log(save)  But now i am getting a tainted canvas can not be exported error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your brush image taints the canvas and will prevent toDataURL.

You will have to:

- configure your server to deliver your images in a CORS compliant way: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/howto/use-cors-with-all-modern-browsers

or

- host your images on a cloud site that has server headers set to allow cross-domain sharing

In either event, on the client-side you must also set the crossOrigin flag avoid having the browser set the canvas as tainted:

```
brush.crossOrigin="anonymous";

brush.src="...";
```